# Where does directshow get image dimensions from?

Tags: image, c#-4.0, image-processing, directshow, directshow.net

We are using a directshow interface to capture images from a video stream. These images are presented in a fixed size window.

Once we have captured an image we store it as a bitmap.  Downstream we have the ability to add annotation to the image, for example letters in a fixed size font.

In one of our desktop environments, the annotation has started appearing at half the size that it normally appears at. This implies that the image we are merging the text onto has dimensions that are maybe twice as large.

The system that this happens on is a shared resource as in some unknown individual has installed software on the system that differs from our baseline.

We have two approaches - the 1st is to reimage the system to get our default text size behaviour back. The 2nd is to figure out how directshow manages image dimensions so that we can set the scaling on the image correctly.

A survey of the directshow literature indicates that the above is not a trivial task. The original work was done by another team that did not document what they did. Can anybody point us in the direction of what directshow object we want to deal with to properly size the sampled image?

Answer (score 2):

DirectShow - as a framework - does not deal with resolutions directly. Your video source (such as capture hardware) is capable of providing video feed in certain resolution which you possibly can change. You normally use `IAMStreamConfig` as described in [Configure the Video Output Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd387907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to choose capture resolution.

Sometimes you cannot affect capture resolution and you need to resample the image in whatever dimensions you captured it. There is no stock filter for this, however Media Foundation provides a suitable [`Video Resizer DSP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819491%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which does most of the task. Unfortunately it does not fit DirectShow pipeline smoothly, so you need fitting and/or custom filter for resizing.

Answer (score 2):

When filters connect in DirectShow, they have an `AM_MEDIA_TYPE`. Here you will find a `VIDEOINFOHEADER` with a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` and this header has a biWidth and biHeight.
Try to build the FilterGraph manually (with GraphEdit or [GraphStudioNext](http://code.google.com/p/graph-studio-next/)) and inspect these fields.

Comment: the bitmap info header indicates that the resolution on the image that we are having problems with is about half of one of our images from the system where it works correctly. now to figure out why...